# How to select list items using button in selenium webdriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

Here is code that I am using firstly I am clicking on the button then the list of items is shown and I try to select from the list but it said that `Index=0`, `Size=0` when I use Xpath. When I use the `class_name` it said "Element not Visible".
Here is code for this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("add_new_item_btn")).click();
Thread.sleep(6000);
java.util.List<WebElement> listItems1 = driver.findElements(By.className("dropdown-menu"));
listItems1.get(0).click();
```

Here is the code in the the inspect element:

```html
<div class="dropdown open">
    <button class="btn-blue-simple btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="add_new_item_btn" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
      Add
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">

        <li>
          <a class="pull-left" onclick="showPopup(&quot;Add Labor Item&quot;, '/quote_items/new?item_type=labor&amp;product_category_id=1912275102536303582&amp;quote_id=1949426380886245765')" href="javascript:void(0)">Labor</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="pull-left" onclick="showPopup(&quot;Add Parts Item&quot;, '/quote_items/new?item_type=part&amp;product_category_id=1912275102796350432&amp;quote_id=1949426380886245765')" href="javascript:void(0)">Parts</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="pull-left" onclick="showPopup(&quot;Add Warranties Item&quot;, '/quote_items/new?item_type=warranty&amp;product_category_id=1912275103022842850&amp;quote_id=1949426380886245765')" href="javascript:void(0)">Warranties</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens when you change driver.findElements(By.className("dropdown-menu")); to use the "pull-left" class?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking at the upper hierarchy in the DOM. 
Try the below code; the intent is to click on the first index.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("add_new_item_btn")).click();
// some explicit wait goes here
List<WebElement> dropdown_items = new ArrayList<>();
dropdown_items = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='dropdown open']//li//a"));
dropdown_items.get(0).click()
```

After this proof works, you might need to refactor this to a method to imitate the behavior of an actual Select class over your dropdown.